# is there any advantage of using SQLitestatement bindstring method instead of simple string concatenation for executing sql statements

Tags: java, android, string, sqlite, android-sqlite

I wanted to insert values in a table in an SQLite Database in Android Studio.I wanted to ask which method should I prefer from the given two methods below.
I learned the first method from a course,but I want to use the second method.That's why I am asking the question

articleId,articleContent and articleTitle are all of type string.

Please specify the pros and cons of each method if you can.You may suggest another method if you want to.

```java
String sql = "INSERT INTO articles (articleId, title, content) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
SQLiteStatement statement = articlesDB.compileStatement(sql);
statement.bindString(1, articleId);
statement.bindString(2, articleTitle);
statement.bindString(3, articleContent);
statement.execute();
```

OR  simply using string concatenation:

```sql
sqliteDatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO articles (articleId, title, content) VALUES (" + articleId + ", " + articleTitle + ", " + articleContent + ")");
```

Comment: Yes to avoid SQL Injections and Syntax errors

Comment: Yes, you should use bindString instead of string concatenation to avoid [this kind of issues](https://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: yep, sql injections, and issues with values that have `"` characters and the like, but in your particular case use `SQLiteDatabase#insert` method instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes, it is always recommended to use `bindString()` to avoid possible attacks in your database through SQL Injection.**

In your particular case, it seems that, the values to be inserted are from your code only, not from any dynamic input source - e.g. user input. In that case, it could be safe to use any of the methods you mentioned in your question.

In your case, in stead of string concatenation, you may also use `insert()` from `SQLiteDatabase` class, which is safe from any syntax error:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("articleId", articleId);
values.put("title", articleTitle);
values.put("content", articleContent);
db.insert("articles", null, values);
```

It returns the row ID of the newly inserted row, or -1 if an error occurred.

However, if you are taking the values from user input, then using string concatenation makes your database completely vulnerable to potential attackers. That's why it is always recommended to use `bindString()` method of `SQLiteProgram` class to execute sql where we need to pass values.

Another reason is, `bindString()` can invoke `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`. So, using this method can be helpful for exception handling and debugging purpose in case any syntax error occurs.